# Not able to connect to firebase and Auth

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

Hi in my app till yesterday i was able to connect firebase and retrieve the data and post the data to firebase and mobile authentication also successful but today, i'm unable to connect firebase to my app and authentication to mobile number is also not successful can soomeone help me out to resolve this issue.I have already done setup at firebase and everything was fine till yesterday. today its not working.Xcode 10.1, ios 12, Firebase realtime database

Comment: Im using Xocde 10.1 and ios 12 version

Comment: There's really no way to answer this question as it could be anything from a firewall issue to a problem with your code to needing to clean and rebuild your project. We would need more to go on. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What will be the firewall issue can you please let me know, how to get to know its a firewall issue ??

Comment: A [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) could be preventing incoming our outgoing communications to the internet. However, no way for us to know. You should also take a look at the two links I included in my prior comment and update you questions showing you code and where it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase iOS SDK updated March 29 as showed here: https://firebase.google.com/support/releases
Try deleting and re-downloading the `GoogleService-Info.plist`, this should resolve your problem.

Comment: yes updated yesterday itself firebase and downloaded GoogleService-Info.plist file too.